# VBA for Each loop

Tags: vba, call, foreach-loop-container

Hi I do have a problem with for each elements in the range. I would like to use for each loop and for each element of that collection certain action must be taken meaning another sub procedure, everything works fine until  first time. For the second element macro lives the loop does not continue what is wrong here HOW SHOULD I AVOID THIS?

Maybe is some better way to do some tasks for each elements in particular range.

In my case I do have 8 such ranges each consists of 20 elements.

NOTE if Im not calling `Hiding_and_Creating_Dump(Celly)` inside loop everything works fine.

PLEASE ADVICE

```
For Each Items In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BU_SELECTOR").Range("A47:H47")

    Debug.Print Items

    Select Case Items.Value
        Case Is = "ASCButton"
            If ASCButton = True Then
                For Each Celly In Workbooks(XLSname).Sheets("lookups").Range(Range_ASC)
                    Debug.Print Celly
                    CommSheetName = Celly.Value
                    Call Hiding_and_Creating_Dump(Celly)
                Next Celly
            End If

        Case Is = "ICOButton"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3kiY.png)

Comment: Its likely you are changing the range over which you are iterating.  We'd need to see the Hiding_and_Creating function to be sure.  If you are changing the range then you will probably need to revert to a standard for loop and count down the range .

Comment: You need an 'Next Items' for one thing.  See how you have 'For Each Celly' and 'Next Celly'.  It's the same concept for the 'Items'.  It won't even compile without that.

Comment: Hi All, many thanks for looking in to my code.Exatcly I’ve took a closer look to my variables and in deed my rangę changed because i was reffering to another sheet which at the and of procedurę have Been closed, my bed .Once again many thanks for your support